# How to add SLIDE DOWN/SLIDE UP function for php selects from database?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Been trying to add SLIDE UP/SLIDE DOWN function to a PHP SELECT from a table , but unfortunately it seems like i m kinda missing something.

My code has already a slide up/down function init, it relates to the textarea and submit button. Now i need the same function for the question and answer lines. where the question is been called by table-1 and answer from table-2.

i would make question as a link so that when we click on it the list of answers from table-2 will slidedown.

My code as follows::

```
<div class="name">

                            <?php 
                            $sql = "SELECT * FROM input ORDER BY date DESC";
                            $result = $conn->query($sql);

                            if ($result->num_rows > 0) { 
                            $index = 0; 
                            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 
                              $index++; 
                            $myid = $row["id"] ;
                            $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM output WHERE question_id = $myid ORDER BY date DESC";

                            $result2 = $conn->query($sql2);


                            ?>

    <div id="q">
        <B><big><font color= #ba4a00> Q:</font></big><a class="About" href="#" class="question" id="question_'.$index.'"> <?php echo $row["question"]; ?></a> </B>

                    <?php 
                            echo '<button class="add" id="add_'.$index.'"><B>Add Answer</B></button>';
                            echo '<form style="display:none;" name="answer_'.$index.'" method="post" action="output.php">'; // I dont think openning form from row to row would be nice!
                            echo '<input type="hidden" name="questionid" value="'. $row['id'].'"/>';
                            echo '<textarea  type="text" class="addtext" name="addtext" required id="addtext_'.$index.'" placeholder="Please type your answer here.."  ></textarea>';
                            echo '<button onClick="addsubmit('.$index.');" type="submit" id="addsubmit_'.$index.'" class="addsubmit"><B>Submit</B></button>';
                            echo '</form>';
                        ?>
        <small><p><?php echo $row["date"]; ?></p></small>

        <?php 

            if ($result2->num_rows > 0) {
            while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
        ?>
        <div name="answ" id="answ_'.$index.'">
        <B><big><font color= #ba4a00> A:</font></B></big> <small><?php echo $row2["answer"]; ?></small></br>
        </div>


        <?php 
                }
            } else {
                    echo "No Answers Yet";
                        }


        ?>

    </div>
    <?php     }
                 } else {
                    echo "0 results";
                        }
                    $conn->close();
    ?>
</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.question').click(function(e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent().find('answ').slideDown('slow');
        });


        $(window).click(function(e) {
            console.log( $(e.target) );
            if( !$(e.target).is('answ') ){
            $('answ').slideUp();
          } 

        });
    });

</script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.add').click(function(e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent().find('form').slideDown('slow');
            $(this).parent().find('form textarea.addtext').focus();
            $(this).hide();
        });

        $('form').click(function(e){
            e.stopPropagation();
        });

        $(window).click(function(e) {
            console.log( $(e.target) );
            if( !$(e.target).is('form') ){
            $('.add').show();
            $('form').slideUp();
          } 

        });
    });

</script>
```

I hope the code is clear to understand. Any suggestions are Appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

With PHP you are making the selects dynamically on jquery will work on dynamic elements only if you write the delegate function for it.

Write your function like this it will work on the elements

```
$(document).on('click', '.question', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().find('answ').slideDown('slow');
});
```

Comment: what do u mean by that?

Comment: i needed the slidedown/slide up function for answers when question is clicked....

Comment: you mean like jsfiddle...?

Comment: Can you take a look at this one mate..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39330887/slide-up-slide-down-is-not-working-for-selected-table-rows-from-db?noredirect=1#comment65993670_39330887